# ZXing for QR codes

Tags: android, qr-code, zxing

In my android application I need the **QR code reader**, so after lots of search, I ended up with the point that there is no need to implement **QR code encode/decoder** from scratch and that I can use **ZXing** library to do the task. but now im stuck with HOW to integrate **ZXing** library in my code, and then how to retrieve the scanned data into a string to my project? I know, this question might be a stupid one but Im newly introduced to such a topic.
 Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By far the simplest, if you aren't in a position to write a full scanning app, is not to write a full scanning app. Integrate with an existing one by Intent in 10 minutes: https://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent

Comment: A stupid question right here: what do I need to put in my project related to ZXing? Do I have to put the full source code or what?

Comment: No just android-integration.jar in libs/.

Answer (score 1):

The [ZXing wiki](https://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent) has instructions on how to do this easily.

Basically you include some simple code that starts the ZXing Android app and then retreive the result in onActivityResult().